# Docker - Why does publishing 80:80 work but not 80:8080?

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

TL;DR only able to access container via port 8080 when doing `docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:8080 --name web nginx` and am wondering why. Works when doing `docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:80 --name web nginx`(able to access container via port 80).

Hey all!

I have Docker running on a Raspberry Pi 4 that I'd like to use to host a couple of different services. I want to use Nginx as a reverse proxy in order to better protect my device.

Following [this](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-official-nginx-docker-image/) guide to setup an Nginx container, I ran `docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web nginx` just to see if it was doing as I expected it to run. That worked (when I went to :8080, it displayed the 'welcome to nginx' page).

However, I don't want to have to type :8080; I want to auto redirect HTTP requests without having to type a port number so I tried `docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:8080 --name web nginx`. No luck - for some reason I am only able to get the welcome page if I specify :8080 still.

I finally was able to get it to work by binding port 80:80 (e.g. `docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:80 --name web nginx`) but I'm a little confused on why that worked and not 80:8080.

To my understanding, `docker run -p 80:8080` should publish port 80 of the device to the exposed port 8080 of the container, which should forward all HTTP traffic to that container. Why am I still only able to access Nginx via port 8080? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx listens on port 80. So `-p 8080:80` forwards your host port 8080 to the container's port 80. `-p 80:8080` does the opposite: forward your host's port 80 (http) to the container's port 8080. But there's nothing listening on port 8080 in your container.

If you want to forward your host's http port 80 to the container's port 80 (on which nginx is listening), use `-p 80:80`.

The syntax for specifying port forwards with docker is: `hostip:hostport:containerport`; the `hostip:` part is optional, so `hostport:containerport` alone works too

Comment: Ah I see - so the reason why I need to expose port 80 over port 8080 is because the Nginx container's default exposed port is 80.

Based on that syntax though, when I used `-p 80:8080`, why was I able to access the nginx proxy on port 8080? Shouldn't it be port 80 (since I'm forwarding my host device's port 80 to the container's port 8080)? UPDATE: nvm I tried it again and it works as expected now; guessing I mixed up device ips or smth

Comment: @KevinChou `-p 80:8080` doesn't allow you to access nginx from your host on port 8080. If it worked, something else was responding or forwarding. Nitpicking: you are not _exposing_ ports, you are forwarding them. `EXPOSE …` in Dockerfiles does nothing except documenting. You can access ports even if they are not marked with `EXPOSE` as soon as an application is listening on the port.